# Syncfusion SfRating ValueChanged Event To Command in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, command, prism, behavior, syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion SfRating control on my xamarin forms view.
I want to handle **ValueChanged event** in Prism ViewModel.

XAML :

```
xmlns:rating="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms"
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"

    <rating:SfRating ItemSize="40" ItemSpacing="15" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <rating:SfRating.RatingSettings>
            <rating:SfRatingSettings RatedFill="Yellow"/>
        </rating:SfRating.RatingSettings>

        <rating:SfRating.Behaviors>
            <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ValueChanged" EventArgsParameterPath="Value" Command="{Binding RatingValueChanged}" />
        </rating:SfRating.Behaviors>
    </rating:SfRating>
```

But an Exception accurs : System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'Syncfusion.SfRating.XForms.ValueEventArgs' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.EventArgs' of method 'Void Invoke(System.Object, System.EventArgs)'
Parameter name: arg1

What's wrong?
How can I send ValueChangedEventArgs e parameter of event to command?

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue with SfRating is due to ValueChangedEventArgs that is not inheritted from EventArgs. We have already fixed the issue and the new version with the fix will be rolled out by the end of August 2018.

Note: I'm working for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Paul Anderson

Comment: Ok I will wait until that date. Xamarin forms has very less free plugin.